# While loop not working problem

Tags: procedural-programming, sequence

I am new to Mathematica ,and I am trying to implement this while loop which adds all odd Fibonacci numbers less than or equal to 2 million but it keeps outputting 0 for sum.
Any solutions for that?

Here is the code:

```
sum = 0;
i = 0;
while[Fibonacci[i] <= 2000000, 
 if[OddQ[Fibonacci[i]], s += Fibonacci[i]]; i++];
s
```

Comment: You appear to be confusing `sum` and `s` variables

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Change `s` to `sum` and capitalize `While` as built-in function names start with an uppercase letter.

Comment: I changed the s in last line to sum, capitalized the w in While and the I in If, but the output is still 0

Comment: What about the `s` in the loop?

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem
thanks a lot to all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Commands in MMA are capitalized. You need "While" and "If". Then s and sum are 2 different variables.

Here is your corrected code:

```
sum = 0;
i = 0;
While[Fibonacci[i] <= 2000000, 
  If[OddQ[Fibonacci[i]], sum += Fibonacci[i]]; i++];
sum
```

(* 2435423 *)

Answer (score 2):

For a non-procedural alternative, one could first find the maximum value of $n$ for which $F(n) \leq 2 000000$, then generate all Fibonacci numbers up to that index, select the odd ones, and sum them:

```
maxn = NArgMax[{x, Fibonacci[x] <= 2000000}, x]
Total@ Select[Fibonacci[Range@ Floor@ maxn], OddQ]

(* Out:
 31.8225
 2 435 423
*)
```

This, of course, leads to the same result as the `While` calculation.

---

Instead of using a maximization, you could also use `FindRoot` to estimate the index you seek:

```
FindRoot[Fibonacci[x] == 2000000, {x, 20}]
(*  {x -> 31.8225} *)
```